# pandas: Boolean indexing with multi index

Tags: python, pandas

There are many questions here with similar titles, but I couldn't find one that's addressing this issue.

I have dataframes from many different origins, and I want to filter one by the other. Using boolean indexing works great when the boolean series is the same size as the filtered dataframe, but not when the size of the series is the same as a *higher level index* of the filtered dataframe.

In short, let's say I have this dataframe:

```
In [4]: df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 
                           'b':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], 
                           'c':range(9)}).set_index(['a', 'b'])
Out[4]: 
     c
a b   
1 1  0
  2  1
  3  2
2 1  3
  2  4
  3  5
3 1  6
  2  7
  3  8
```

And this series:

```
In [5]: filt = pd.Series({1:True, 2:False, 3:True})
Out[6]: 
1     True
2    False
3     True
dtype: bool
```

And the output I want is this:

```
     c
a b   
1 1  0
  2  1
  3  2
3 1  6
  2  7
  3  8
```

I am not looking for solutions that are not using the `filt` series, such as:

```
df[df.index.get_level_values('a') != 2]
df[df.index.get_level_values('a').isin([1,3])]
```

I want to know if I can use my input `filt` series as is, as I would use a filter on c:

```
filt = df.c < 7
df[filt]
```

Comment: What about `df[df.index.get_level_values('a').isin(filt)]`?  I don't think you can do what you want in the way you suggest, because your series is not "the same size" as one level of the MultiIndex.  The normal display only *shows* you three values for that level, but each level of the MultiIndex is actually the same length as the whole DataFrame.

Comment: @BrenBarn If anything, it would have to be `df[df.index.get_level_values('a').isin(filt[filt].index)]`. And I guess that "no, that's impossible" is a fair answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you transform your index 'a' back to a column, you can do it as follows:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 
                       'b':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], 
                       'c':range(9)})
>>> filt = pd.Series({1:True, 2:False, 3:True})
>>> df[filt[df['a']].values]
   a  b  c
0  1  1  0
1  1  2  1
2  1  3  2
6  3  1  6
7  3  2  7
8  3  3  8
```

**edit**.
As suggested by @joris, this works also with indices. Here is the code for your sample data:

```
>>> df[filt[df.index.get_level_values('a')].values]
     c
a b   
1 1  0
  2  1
  3  2
3 1  6
  2  7
  3  8
```

Comment: This is very nice! I thought it would have been also possible to do `df[filt[df.index.get_level_values('a')]]` without resetting the index, but this results in `ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis`, anyway to bypass that?

Comment: @Korem It does work like you posted, you only forgot the `.values` like in the answer.

Comment: @joris This seems to be working faster (benchmarked on real, large-scale data), so I'll accept this one - but thanks for the help!

Answer (score 3):

If the boolean series is not aligned with the dataframe you want to index it with, you can first explicitely align it with [`align`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.align.html):

```
In [25]: df_aligned, filt_aligned = df.align(filt.to_frame(), level=0, axis=0)

In [26]: filt_aligned
Out[26]:
         0
a b
1 1   True
  2   True
  3   True
2 1  False
  2  False
  3  False
3 1   True
  2   True
  3   True
```

And then you can index with it:

```
In [27]: df[filt_aligned[0]]
Out[27]:
     c
a b
1 1  0
  2  1
  3  2
3 1  6
  2  7
  3  8
```

Note: the align didn't work with a Series, therefore the `to_frame` in the align call, and therefore the `[0]` above to get back the series.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [pd.IndexSlicer](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IndexSlice.html#pandas.IndexSlice).

```
>>> df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[filt[filt].index.values, :], :]
     c
a b   
1 1  0
  2  1
  3  2
3 1  6
  2  7
  3  8
```

where `filt[filt].index.values` is just `[1, 3]`. In other words

```
>>> df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[[1, 3], :]]
     c
a b   
1 1  0
  2  1
  3  2
3 1  6
  2  7
  3  8
```

so if you design your filter construction a bit differently, the expression gets shorter. The advantave over [Emanuele Paolini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25837542/7128154)'s solution `df[filt[df.index.get_level_values('a')].values]` is, that you have more control over the indexing.

The topic of multiindex slicing is covered in more depth [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#using-slicers).

**Here the full code**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 'b':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], 'c':range(9)}).set_index(['a', 'b'])
filt = pd.Series({1:True, 2:False, 3:True})

print(df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[[1, 3], :]])
print(df.loc[(df.index.levels[0].values[filt], slice(None)), :])
print(df.loc[pd.IndexSlice[filt[filt].index.values, :], :])
```

Answer (score 1):

The more readable (to my liking) solution is to reindex the boolean series (dataframe) to match index of the multi-index df:

```
df.loc[filt.reindex(df.index, level='a')]
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing exactly the same problem. I found this question and tried the solutions here, but none of them was efficient enough. My dataframes are: `A = 700k rows x 14 cols`, `B = 100M rows x 3 cols`. `B` has an `MultiIndex`, where the first (high) level is equal to the index of `A`. Let `C` be a slice from `A` of size `10k` rows. My task was to get rows from `B` whose high-level index matches indexes of `C` as fast as possible. `C` is selected at runtime. `A` and `B` are static.

I tried the solutions from here: `get_level_values` takes many seconds, `df.align` didn't even finish giving `MemoryError` (and also took seconds).

The solution which worked for me (in `~300msec` during runtime) is the following:

1. For each `index` value `i` from `A`, find the first and the last (non-inclusive) *positional* indexes in `B` which contain `i` as the first level of MultiIndex. Store these pairs in `A`. This is done once and in advance.
   Example code:

   ```
   def construct_position_indexes(A, B):
       indexes = defaultdict(list)
       prev_index = 0
       for i, cur_index in enumerate(B.index.get_level_values(0)):
           if cur_index != prev_index:
               indexes[cur_index].append(i)
               if prev_index:
                   indexes[prev_index].append(i)
           prev_index = cur_index
       indexes[cur_index].append(i+1)
       index_df = pd.DataFrame(indexes.values(),
                               index=indexes.keys(),
                               columns=['start_index', 'end_index'], dtype=int)
       A = A.join(index_df)
       # they become floats, so we fix that
       A['start_index'] = A.start_index.fillna(0).astype(int)
       A['end_index'] = A.end_index.fillna(0).astype(int)
       return A
   ```
2. At runtime, get positional boundaries from `C` and construct a list of all positional indexes to search for in `B`, and pass them to `B.take()`:

   ```
   def get_slice(B, C):
       all_indexes = []
       for start_index, end_index in zip(
               C.start_index.values, C.end_index.values):
           all_indexes.extend(range(start_index, end_index))
       return B.take(all_indexes)
   ```

I hope it's not too complicated. Essentially, the idea is for each row in `A` store the range of corresponding (positional) indexes of rows in `B`, so that at runtime we can quickly construct the list of all positional indexes to query `B` by.

This is a toy example:

```
A = pd.DataFrame(range(3), columns=['dataA'], index=['A0', 'A1', 'A2'])
print A

    dataA
A0      0
A1      1
A2      2

mindex = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([
    ('A0', 'B0'), ('A0', 'B1'), ('A1', 'B0'), 
    ('A2', 'B0'), ('A2', 'B1'), ('A2', 'B3')])
B = pd.DataFrame(range(6), columns=['dataB'], index=mindex)
print B

       dataB
A0 B0      0
   B1      1
A1 B0      2
A2 B0      3
   B1      4
   B3      5

A = construct_position_indexes(A, B)
print A

    dataA  start_index  end_index
A0      0            0          2
A1      1            2          3
A2      2            3          6

C = A.iloc[[0, 2], :]
print C

    dataA  start_index  end_index
A0      0            0          2
A2      2            3          6

print get_slice(B, C)

       dataB
A0 B0      0
   B1      1
A2 B0      3
   B1      4
   B3      5
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply:

```
df.where(
    filt.rename_axis('a').rename('c').to_frame()
).dropna().astype(int)
```

Explanation:

- `.rename_axis('a')` renames the **index** as `a` (the index we want to filter by)
- `.rename('c')` renames the **column** as `c` (the column that stores the values)
- `.to_frame()` converts this Series into a **DataFrame**, for compatibility with `df`
- `df.where(...)` filters the rows, leaving missing values (`NaN`) where filter is `False`
- `.drop_na()` removes the rows with missing values (in our case where `a == 2`)
- `.astype(int)` converts from `float` back to `int` (not sure why `float` to begin with)

By the way, it seems that `df.where(...)` and `df[...]` behave similarly here, so take your pick.

Comment: Haha. Thanks! I like that your solution begins with "simply" :)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how fast/slow it would be on a large-scale dataframe, but what I sometimes do is

```
df.loc[filt[filt].index]
```

The problem is that the `loc` method only works with boolean inputs on a 1D index. If you provide the values of the first level elements you want to retain, you're good to go. So by filtering `filt` with itself (since it's on a 1D index) and keeping the values from its index, you achieve your goal.

Answer (score 0):

Building on @Markus Dutschke's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58632038/10499953), note that the IndexSlice object can be created just once and then used over and over (even to slice up different objects). I find this creates more readable code, especially when using it twice to slice on *both* MultiIndex rows and columns in the same `.loc`.

Applying this to his answer and simplifying slightly (no need for .values):

```
idx = pd.IndexSlice
df.loc[idx[filt[filt].index, :], :]
```

or the full code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3], 'b':[1,2,3,1,2,3,1,2,3], 'c':range(9)}).set_index(['a', 'b'])
filt = pd.Series({1:True, 2:False, 3:True})
idx = pd.IndexSlice

print(df.loc[idx[[1, 3], :]])
print(df.loc[(df.index.levels[0].values[filt], slice(None)), :])
print(df.loc[idx[filt[filt].index, :], :])
```