# Intersect on Pandas Multiindex

Tags: python, pandas

I want to slice a Multiindex Dataframe. Lets take as an example this df:

```
import pandas as pd

arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'bar','bar', 'foo','foo', 'qux', 'qux', 
'qux','qux', 'qux'],
      ['2', '3', '4','10', '3','10','2','3','6','10','11']]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(11, 4), index=arrays).sort_index()
```

-->

```
               0         1         2         3
bar 10  1.411962 -0.742729  0.950159  1.074269
    2   1.214804 -0.654806 -1.138855  0.609101
    3   0.135363  1.226927 -0.501535 -0.791849
    4   1.118516 -1.340844 -1.365790 -0.099575
foo 10 -0.004108 -0.067574 -0.139101 -0.358282
    3   0.612849 -0.598579  0.923299 -0.218198
qux 10  0.112769 -1.330163  2.195480 -0.347462
    11  0.057467 -0.204044  0.020474 -1.198299
    2   1.011604 -0.411514  0.941112 -0.509703
    3   0.524958 -0.855275  0.257481  0.630311
    6   1.989778 -0.099014  0.302340 -0.067559
```

And now I want to get just the rows where the second index has some values. So lets say I just want rows where the second index contains '2' AND '3' AND '10', so I could do :

```
sliced = df.loc[(slice(None), ['2','3','10']), :]
```

which yields:

```
               0         1         2         3
bar 10  1.411962 -0.742729  0.950159  1.074269
    2   1.214804 -0.654806 -1.138855  0.609101
    3   0.135363  1.226927 -0.501535 -0.791849
foo 10 -0.004108 -0.067574 -0.139101 -0.358282
    3   0.612849 -0.598579  0.923299 -0.218198
qux 10  0.112769 -1.330163  2.195480 -0.347462
    2   1.011604 -0.411514  0.941112 -0.509703
    3   0.524958 -0.855275  0.257481  0.630311
```

but I dont want the row with ['10','3']. So the desired Result would be :

```
               0         1         2         3
bar 10  1.411962 -0.742729  0.950159  1.074269
    2   1.214804 -0.654806 -1.138855  0.609101
    3   0.135363  1.226927 -0.501535 -0.791849
qux 10  0.112769 -1.330163  2.195480 -0.347462
    2   1.011604 -0.411514  0.941112 -0.509703
    3   0.524958 -0.855275  0.257481  0.630311
```

I tried but I could not get my head around how to properly solve this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Nope... don't believe this is possible through slicing.

Answer (score 0):

As COLDSPEED said it does not seem possible threw pure indexing. 
However you can do it in a few steps through a groupby statement. 
If we take your code again

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
arrays = [['bar', 'bar', 'bar','bar', 'foo','foo', 'qux', 'qux', 
'qux','qux', 'qux'],
      ['2', '3', '4','10', '3','10','2','3','6','10','11']]
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(11, 4), index=arrays).sort_index()
# your slice
col_list = ['2','3','10']
sliced = df.loc[(slice(None), col_list), :]
```

Then we can apply a groupby to find the number of items per first level index. Then we compare it to the number of items you are expecting. Finally we use the boolean mask created in order to filter our dataframe (more details on that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25837440/pandas-boolean-indexing-with-multi-index)).

```
>>> mask = sliced.groupby(level=0)[0].count() == len(col_list)
>>> sliced[mask[sliced.index.get_level_values(0)].values]

               0         1         2         3
bar 10  0.026192 -1.367292 -1.732297 -0.174405
    2  -0.351960  0.563901  0.634585 -0.540770
    3   0.489480  0.265043  0.989557  0.783377
qux 10  0.544202 -0.061462  1.020261 -2.170451
    2  -0.506330  0.335722 -0.303334 -0.916619
    3   0.877082  0.235224  0.868546  2.197707
```